# C# wrong color preview image

Tags: c#, listview, colors, preview

Im new in building apps with C#. Im working with images and doing some analysis with them. After clicking on image i get RGB value of current pixel. All values are next stored in listview with preview image. And there is my problem. The preview image is not the same, as RGB value of the current pixel. If i did this same with pictureboxes, then the colors were correct. But i dont know how to implement pictureboxes into listView or listBox. 
There is my source code, which create bitmap for my color preview .

```
private Image createImage(Color col)
    {
      PixelFormat px_format = PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb;

      int pixelFormatSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(px_format) / 8;
      int stride = 16 * pixelFormatSize;
      int padding = (stride % 4);
      stride += padding == 0 ? 0 : 4 - padding; //pad out to multiple of 4
      SharedPinnedByteArray byteArray = new SharedPinnedByteArray(stride * 16);
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16, stride, px_format, byteArray.bitPtr);
      Graphics gpx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
      SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(col);
      gpx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 16, 16);
      gpx.Dispose();
      return bmp;
    }
```

And here is how im calling function and adding items to listView

```
listView1.SmallImageList.Images.Add(createImage(color));
listView1.Items.Add(color.R.ToString() + "," + color.G.ToString() + "," + color.B.ToString() + ",", listView1.SmallImageList.Images.Count - 1);
```

Best regards

Gabriel

Comment: In what it is different? What is the color format size of the `ImageList` assigned to `listView1.SmallImageList`?

Comment: Problem solved. Default listView color depth is set to 8bit. I changed it into 32bit.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant `'color depth'`.

Comment: How exactly did you change the list view's color depth?

Answer (score 0):

Since the default list view color depth is 8 bit, you need to change it to 24 or 32 bit:

```
listView1.SmallImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit;
```